# How to know which URL/Landing pages are gaining traffic in Google using analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

When we get more traffic, i.e increase in Google organic results, How do we know, Which URLs are gaining traffic and how much traffic is gained over the last few weeks ?

And in similar way, How do we know the top 10 losers(landing pages) in Google organic in last 2 months, Weekly data needed.

How can I achieve this in Google analytics.

In short: How to know the top gainers and losers with data per week/month?

Comment: You may find the Google Search Consoles Performance report provides what you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

From the sidebar - Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium. Filter to see only google / organic, add Landing page as a Secondary dimension